# jQuery animate right

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

http://jsfiddle.net/hashie5/ZKwA6/

My links slide to the right now, but they don't align right.
I need an animate with `text-align:right` or `float:right`.
Also when you leave link, the text should align left again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not quite yet what you want but if you add class right and remove it, it may look towards what you want

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('.menu td').delegate('', 'mouseover', function() {
        $(this).find('a').animate({
            "left": "0",
        }, 500);
        $(this).addClass('right');
    });
    $('.menu td').delegate('', 'mouseout', function() {
        $(this).find('a').attr('style', 'left:0;');
        $(this).removeClass('right');
    });
});​
```

Note that I set the animiation of Left to 0... you can find out in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZKwA6/26/)

The fiddle shows left / right only, and I think you want to animate it to the right. But animating it from left to right with changing the alignment may take some additional calculations

EDIT: Added combination of the answers as they all show a piece of solution

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('.menu td').delegate('', 'mouseover', function() {
        $(this).find('a').stop().animate({
            "left": $(this).width() - $(this).find('a').width()
        }, 500);
    });
    $('.menu td').delegate('', 'mouseout', function() {
       $(this).find('a').stop().animate({
           "left": "0",
        }, 500);
   });
});​
```

Credits to : Alex Ball, Raminson, Esailija

Comment: this is what i need, but now now I still need the animate! thanks

Comment: You need a combination from the answers. Use the .Stops() plus the calculation for left().

Answer (score 2):

To align right, use above code, and change

```
"left":"140"
```

with

```
"left": $(this).width() - $(this).find('a').width()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this so, ti should work.

```
$('document').ready(function() {

   $('.menu td').hover(
      function() {
      var a =  $(this).find('a').first();
      a.css('position', 'relative')
       .stop().animate({ left: $(this).width() - a.width()}); 
      },
      function() {
        $(this).find('a').first().stop().animate({ left: 0 });
      });
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

try hover method:

```
$('.menu td').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('a').animate({
            "left": "140"
        }, 500);
    },
        function() {
        $(this).find('a').animate({
            "left": "0"
        }, 500);
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZKwA6/10/

using stop();

```
$('.menu td').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('a').stop().animate({
            "left": "140"
        }, 500);
    },
        function() {
        $(this).find('a').stop().animate({
            "left": "0"
        }, 500);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZKwA6/20/

Comment: thanks but the problem is the left: 140, it should just align the text right, now it's still aligned left; left:140 was the best I could do